# Artificial templates

Tags: c++, templates

So, I have the following problem that's been following me around for some time.

A *Shader* draws groups of *vertices*.  Because it is loaded from a text file an into the GPU, OpenGL *does not require it to be typed at all*.

```
struct Shader
{
    // Load that shader from filename
    Shader( string filename ... ) ;
} ;
```

A group of vertices is **typed** in my code

```
VertexArray<VertexPTC> ptcVerts ; // PTC is position, texcoord, color.
```

An array of `ptcVerts` **should only** be drawn by a `ptcShader`.  To try and draw an array of `pcVerts` with a `ptShader` is an error (because color values would be interpreted as texcoords).

So I would like the compiler to flag that kind of error.  Here's how:

```
template<typename T> struct Shader
```

now Shader, *although it never uses `T` at all* is typed at compile time.  The compiler now enforces the restriction that a `VertexArray<VertexPTC>` be drawn by a `Shader<VertexPTC>`.

Is this ***good or bad***?  Shader *does not need or use `T`*, so I fear my use of templates is somehow a misuse.

Comment: What makes `Shader<VertexPTC>` a `ptcShader`? Or am I misunderstanding what's happening here?

Comment: Just by name convention.  a `ptcShader` was named so that the programmer remembers only to use it on `ptcVerts`.

Comment: Then how does "The compiler now enforces the restriction that a `VertexArray<VertexPTC>` be drawn by a `Shader<VertexPTC>`" work?

Comment: I can't realy point out why it is bad, it just does not feel right for me exectly from the reason you stated. Adding templates everywhere does solve many problems but from my experience it also adds many problems later on the road. What i would do is create a new with getters that will allways give the corresponding array and shader. How it is implemented is your choise, personally i would not go with templates.

Comment: You used template as a sort of a sticked-on type tag/label, to tell the compiler to catch some sorts of errors during compilation. Well, sounds perfectly reasonable to me: the type system exists exactly for that purpose.

Comment: You probably want `const std::string &filename` instead of `std::string filename`, but I'm probably splitting hairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is a misuse**.  The use of templates is not *free*, there are difficulties added when you templatize a class that you are willing to deal with *for the advantages of using a template* there.

I got into trouble with this much later when I needed a generic way to handle a `Shader` -- I needed a way to disable the last bound `Shader`, and it didn't matter what type it was.

I had to either artificially factor in a subclass from which `Shader<T>` derives, or just delete the template parameter `T` from the Shader class.

But I actually found an even better way to do it.  Simply define your class normally:

```
struct Shader
{
  // complete, untemplatized definition.  If it doesn't use T
  // internally, THEN DO NOT INTRODUCE ARTIFICIAL DEPENDENCE ON T!
} ;
```

But then I define:

```
template <typename T> struct TShader : public Shader { } ;
```

SO now, *when you want* the compiler to enforce type, use the 2nd `TShader<T>` definition.  If you don't need the compiler to enforce type, use the fully functional base class `Shader` definition.

This gives you the best of both worlds. You can always treat a `TShader<T>` as its untemplatized base class when needed, without losing functionality or having to write an abstract interface when one is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're expressing a real-world constraint in code.  Your examples here don't actually show that buying you anything here, so going on the evidence I'd wonder whether it's redundant to express it, or irrelevant to any situation that will actually arise.  But if you're ever going to have different kinds of shaders for different kinds of vertex datasets, I'd say you've hit on exactly the right way to express this here.

Comment: It's _very_ easy to try and draw something with the wrong shader!

Comment: Yep. Just because the type argument isn’t used doesn’t mean the type parameter serves no purpose. Types introduced by this technique are called [phantom types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type) in Haskell. They’re widely used in many languages to avoid common bugs arising from mixing of incompatible units (`3.0<m/s>` in F#), coordinate spaces (`Point<WorldCoords>`), and axes (`Offset<XAxis>`), to name a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the compiler to prevent you from doing the wrong thing, one way is to do this:

```
class ShaderPTC
{
public:
   ShaderPTC( string filename, <other params> );
   void Draw( VertexArray<VertexPTC>& Vertices );
   ~ShaderPTC();
private:
   Shader m_shader;
}
```

and

```
class ShaderPC
{
public:
   ShaderPC( string filename, <other params> );
   void Draw( VertexArray<VertexPC>& Vertices );
   ~ShaderPC();
private:
   Shader m_shader;
}
```

You make sure the constructors create the appropriate shader internally and pass objects of this class by pointer/references so that you don't have to take care about copying the wrapped shader (you might want to make the copy constructors/assignment private as well).

Since the `Draw` function only accepts the correct type of vertex array and the inner shader is not exposed you can't pass the wrong parameters.

If the code you have to write in the constructors and the `Draw` functions is generic you can make this a template class. Otherwise you would have to specialize the template anyway giving the template approach no real benefit.

While correctly naming your variables *might* prevent such problems, correctly *typing* the variables will be much harder to break.

Comment: And notice how this solution is actually doing template instantiation by hands. Why not ask the compiler to write this boilerplate code?

Comment: @Joker_vD because writing the "boilerplate" might actually require *less* typing. It also doesn't have the "mental cost" templates might have on less experienced programmers.

Comment: this is pretty much what i meant in my comment, just note that the compiler should not be the one responsible of the shader creation, pass it as a pareter...

Comment: @user1708860 if the class doesn't handle creating the shader you might instantiate `ShaderPC` with a `ptcShader` and then you are back to relying on programmers passing the correct parameter. If the constructor does it you only have to verify that *it* does what you expect. Otherwise you have to verify that *all* code that instantiates a shader wrapper does it with the correct shader...

Comment: Use a factory then, it's not the constructor's job.

Comment: @Andei I would argue that tons of wrapping classes are more "mentally expensive" than a simple type tag (in a form of a template parameter, or whatever), but maybe it's subjective.

Comment: @Joker_vD Perhaps there's a threshold of sorts. I wouldn't use a template for just the PTC and PC mentioned here but almost surely if there were multiple types or if types that could be added by further development.

Comment: Isn't that a lot of code replication for `ShaderPTC`, `ShaderPTcC`, `ShaderPC`, `ShaderPTTC`, `ShaderPTTTTC`? (there are a lot of vertex format types!)

Comment: @bobobobo The *key* is that each wrapper is associated via the `Draw` method to a type of array. That adds type safety and allows the compiler to flag incorrect uses. You can implement the wrappers via templates or by hand (via templates if there are a lot of types...).